# Jquery FullCalendar refetch resources using a filter

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using an ajax request to fetch both of my events and resources by post a request to a php file where I have some mysql queries. I have a function that is triggers by changes in some of my form elements called searchFilter(). Within this function I am am to refetch the events by using an ajax request by first removing the events, running a new ajax request, then adding the results as a source and finally rerendering the events

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
        $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        type: 'POST', // Send post data
        data: 'type=fetchall',
        data: {
            type        : 'fetchall',
            keywords    : keywords,
            sortBy      : sortBy,
            building    : building,
            month       : month,
            approve     : approve,
            classes     : 'y',
            search      : 'search'
        },
        async: false,
        success: function(s){
            json_events = s;                                
        }
    });     
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', JSON.parse(json_events)); 
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
```

I have been trying to do the same thing with the Resources, but have been unable to accomplish this with

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchResources' );
```

My method for fetching the Resources originally looks like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',
    type: 'POST', // Send post data
    data: 'type=resources',
        async: false,
        success: function(s){
            json_resources = s;
            $("#resources").html(json_resources);
        }
    });
```

then later ofcourse

```
resources: JSON.parse(json_resources),
```

I am a bit of a jquery novice. I am hoping someone could possibly lead me in the right directly. If I have left any necessary information, please let me know.

Comment: `async: false`...why?? You're using callbacks properly to fetch the response. There's no need for this at all. It just creates bad user experience (locks up the browser while the request is running, so it feels like the browser has crashed). Also it's been deprecated, so you can expect it to stop working at some point in future.

Comment: Your problem is because json_resources is a static list of JSON objects. There's no connection back to how it was retrieved from the server. For all fullCalendar knows, you could have typed it in manually to the web page. There's nothing to re-fetch. You need to define "resources" in your calendar as a callback function, as per the docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/resources_function/ . That way when you run refetchResources, fullCalendar calls the function, which gets fresh resource data from the server, instead of just re-loading the same static list.